# Remove duplicate rows after imputing first row values

Tags: python, r, duplicates

I have a dataframe whereby there are duplicate row IDs. I need to clean this so that extra columns hold the non repeated data in the original ID's row.

I have already marked each duplicate in a separate column (no hard maximum duplicates as live dataset):

```
df_dupe_count<-df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(occurrence=1:n())
```

This gives the following:

| ID | Value | occurrence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | c | 1 |
| A | d | 2 |
| B | e | 1 |

I then created n columns to fill using the following code:

```
`df[paste("Value",2:max(table(df$ID)))] <- NA`
```

At this point I'm stuck. The output I'd like is:

| ID | Value | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | c | d |
| B | e | NA |

I can do the occurrence column and duplicate rows removal, but how do I extract the Values and impute them into first occurrence beforehand?

Happy for answers in R preferably but can convert df into pandas if Python is more suited

Thanks

Comment: in pandas: `df.pivot(index='ID', columns='occurrence', values='Value').reset_index()`

Comment: Read the online doc for `tidyr::pivot_longer`.  Other solutions exist.

Comment: Try `df_dupe_count %>% pivot_wider(names_from = occurrence, values_from = Value, names_prefix = "Value_")` where `pivot_wider` is from `tidyr` package

Comment: @RonakShah thank you so much, that's worked a treat! I definitely SHOULD have thought doing it that way rather than adding columns and loops and taking away...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should try

```
df %>%
    mutate(occurence = seq_len(n()), .by = ID) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = occurence,
        values_from = Value,
        names_prefix = "Value"
    )
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  ID    Value1 Value2
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 A     c      d
2 B     e      NA
```